# Extending Jquery accordion to rows of a table

Tags: jquery, html-table, accordion

I have a table with collapsible rows. Please check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/soumyazyx/8Xyjy/10/)

I just want to use the Jquery UI accordion as shown [here](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

I am trying to apply accordion to the below structure :

```
<table>
    <tbody class="category">
        <tr><td>Category - 1</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="subcategory">
        <tr><td>Sub Cateogry 1.1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Sub Cateogry 1.2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="category">
       <tr><td>Category - 2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="subcategory">
       <tr><td>Sub Cateogry 2.1</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I understand that ordered list is most suitable for this type of structure.But due to some restrictions, table needs to be used.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [header](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-header) option of the accordion:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table').accordion({header: '.category' });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c1j7xbkp/

Comment: jsfiddle Link broken :(

Comment: @SteveP 4 years later .. I guess the original fiddle was deleted for some reason. I updated my answer with a new one using a basic example with the provided HTML. The animation is a bit laggy but the functionality is there.