# jQuery-ui accordion on tables with multiple columns

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

There is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046654/extending-jquery-accordion-to-rows-of-a-table), but I don't have enough reputation to comment.

But this does not take into account multiple columns.

I created a fiddle for the same. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Xyjy/998/)

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
      <td>Category - 1</td>
      <td>Category - 2</td>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="category">
    <tr>
      <td>Category - 1</td>
      <td>Category - 2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody class="subcategory">
    <tr>
      <td>Sub Cateogry 1.1</td>
      <td>Sub Cateogry 1.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sub Cateogry 1.3</td>
      <td>Sub Cateogry 1.4</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody class="category">
   <tr>
     <td>Category - 3</td>
     <td>Category - 4</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody class="subcategory">
   <tr>
     <td>Sub Cateogry 2.1.1</td>
     <td>Sub Cateogry 2.1.2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Sub Cateogry 2.1.3</td>
     <td>Sub Cateogry 2.1.4</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

All the 'category' rows come inside the first column and the 'thead' and 'subcategory' rows are outside.

How do I make this right?

Comment: why do you wanna complicate life by using tables?? you can just use divs right?

Comment: I can not use Bootstrap. I tried using divs with "display: table", but it turned out to be exactly like the one above. Any suggestions?

Comment: instead of using jQuery UI's accordion you can use `toggle()` can you share a pic of something which illustrates the final output you are looking for?

Comment: or  you can try this plugin